# Inject custom class into DbContext constructor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I've seen the construction below in several post on StackOverflow but it does not work for me. What I want is to inject the MyProjectsDatabaseOptions object into the ModelContext class. I need that because in the OnModelCreating I need to set a default Schema like so:

```
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(_myProjectsDatabaseOptions.Schema.ToString())
            .UseCollation("USING_NLS_COMP");
```

Im open to other suggestions on how to get this 'Schema' parameter into the DbContext class.

The DbContext class:

```
public partial class ModelContext : DbContext
{
    public ModelContext() // <<== This constructor is called
    {
    }

    private IMyProjectsDatabaseOptions? _myProjectsDatabaseOptions { get; set; } = default!;

    public ModelContext(DbContextOptions<ModelContext> options, IMyProjectsDatabaseOptions myProjectsDatabaseOptions)
        : base(options)
    {
        _myProjectsDatabaseOptions = myProjectsDatabaseOptions;
    }

    ...
}
```

The initialization:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ConfigurationManager>(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMyProjectsDatabaseOptions, MyProjectsDatabaseOptions>();
```

== EDIT ==
In the program.cs:

```
services.AddDbContext<ModelContext>(ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

== End EDIT ==

The options class:

```
namespace MyProjects.Infrastructure
{
    public class MyProjectsDatabaseOptions : IMyProjectsDatabaseOptions
    {
        private ConfigurationManager _configurationManager { get; set; }

        public MyProjectsDatabaseOptions(ConfigurationManager configurationManager)
        {
            _configurationManager = configurationManager;
        }

        public string Schema => _configurationManager?.GetValue<string>("Schema")
            ?? throw new Exception("Schema null");

        public string ConnectionString => _configurationManager?.GetConnectionString($"MyProjects_{Schema}")
            ?? throw new Exception("Connectionstring null");
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you register the `ModelContext` in the IoC container? Or how do you create an object of this class?

Comment: I'm not seeing a registration for `DbContextOptions<ModelContext>`. The DI framework probably recognizes it can't resolve all the dependencies for that constructor, so it [chooses the one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#multiple-constructor-discovery-rules) that doesn't have any parameters.

Comment: This was my bad. The class object I wanted to inject had been copied to another project but was not removed from it's original location. After removing the original classes it started working.